# How do I increase the amplitude of this elastic animation effect?

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation, svg, raphael

I'm using [Raphael.js](http://raphaeljs.com/) to animate an SVG circle's radius on hover. I like the stock `elastic` effect that the library offers, but I'd like to increase the amplitude - i.e., make the circle grow and shrink with a lot more gusto when it's hovered - not with extra speed, but to grow larger and shrink smaller when the effect runs.

I copied the `elastic` function and renamed it `super_elastic`, and have been tinkering with it here:

http://jsfiddle.net/ryWH3/

I have no idea how the function works, so I've just been tinkering with its numerical values to see what happens. So far I haven't found anything that appears to do what I want. Can anyone recommend any modifications to the function (or a different function altogether) that might do what I'm looking for?

Thanks!

---

**UPDATE:**

Thanks for the replies! Sorry, I may not have explained this very well. I'm guessing that the statement "grow larger and shrink smaller" was especially misleading.

I'm aware that the `r` property affects the final radius of the circle after the animation runs; what I'm trying to do, though, is make the `elastic` animation "bounce" with greater amplitude. That is, while the animation will still start and end at the same `r` values that I've set for the circle, I'd like the `elastic` transition to be a lot more dramatic - expand and contract the circle much more aggressively during the transition before arriving at the final `r` values. To do this, I'm assuming that I need to modify the equation used in the `elastic` function to make the effect more dramatic.

Hopefully that makes sense - it's kind of hard to explain without showing an example, but if I had an example, I wouldn't have needed to post this question. ;-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

OK, based on your clarification, here's a new answer.  To expand the effect of the easing (amplification), you need to multiply the easing result with a multiplier like this.

```
return 6 * Math.pow(2, -10 * n) * Math.sin((n - .075) * (2 * Math.PI) / .3) + 1;
```

But, when you do that, you find that the large part of the amplification goes too fast.  The small part goes slow and the large part goes fast.  So, the pace when it's larger needs to be changed.  My guess (which seems to work) was to change `Math.sin()` to `Math.cos()` because that shifts the phase and it seems to work as you can see here: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/fuaNp/39/.

```
return 6 * Math.pow(2, -10 * n) * Math.cos((n - .075) * (2 * Math.PI) / .3) + 1;
```

Other things to understand about this easing function.  This part:

```
(2 * Math.PI) / .3
```

determines how many bounce cycles there are.  The larger that multipler is, the more bounces it will have (but the faster the bounces will go).  The smaller that multipler is, the fewer bounces it will have (and the slower those bounces will go).

This part:

```
Math.pow(2, -10 * n)
```

determines how fast the bounce decays since this value gets smaller the larger n gets which negates the other multipliers as n gets large.  So:

```
Math.pow(2, -5 * n)
```

makes it decay slower (you see more of the larger swings at the beginning and less of the smaller swings at the end.

Comment: That's perfect! Exactly what I was looking for, and I really appreciate the thorough explanation - based on that, I was able to tweak it a bit to get the exact effect I wanted. Thanks so much. Happy New Year!

Answer (score 2):

To make the circle go larger when you hover over it, you change the hovered radius which I've upped to `r: 100` here.  To make the circle smaller, you change the initial size and the unhovered size from 25 to something smaller like this:

```
var paper = Raphael(0, 0, 300, 300),
    circle = paper.circle(150, 150, 10);   // <== change initial radius here to make it smaller

circle.attr({
  'stroke': '#f00',
  'stroke-width': 4,
  'fill': '#fff'
});
circle.hover(function() {
  this.animate({ r: 100 }, 1000, 'super_elastic');   // <== change enlarged size here
}, function() {
  this.animate({ r: 10 }, 1000, 'super_elastic');    // <== change small size here
});

// no changes made to the easing function
Raphael.easing_formulas.super_elastic = function(n) {
  if (n == !!n) {
    return n;
  }
  return Math.pow(2, -10 * n) * Math.sin((n - .075) * (2 * Math.PI) / .3) + 1;
};
```

You can see it here: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/fuaNp/.

The `super_elastic()` function is the easing function which controls what pace the animation moves at different parts of the cycle.  Easing doesn't control the overall amplitude.  That's done with the parameters to the `animate()` method.

If you wanted to slow down the animation, you would increase the time of the animation (make the two `1000` arguments to `animate()` be larger numbers.  If you wanted to speed up the animation, you make those two numbers smaller.  These are milliseconds for the animation.  Smaller numbers means the animation runs in fewer milliseconds (which means faster).

Comment: Thanks for your reply! Please see my update above for clarification.